# Javascript change the src of a table cell

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I am trying to change content of the first cells of rows into some images. Below is my Javascript code which doesn't work. I tried to use `p.appendChild(img)`, but as it's in a for loop, each time I pressed the button that invokes this, it will append another image to that row. I reckon that I am not using `.src` correctly? Can someone please help?

```
    var rowx =document.getElementById(rowid); //the row that I want to change its first cell
    var uri= "baseuri"+rowid;
    img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src= uri;
    var p = rowx.cells[0];
    p.src=img; //this doesn't change the first cell's content.if I use p.appendChild(img) it will append new img each time it gets executed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cells gives you an HTMLCollection of td elements, which do not support a source attribute. if you want to edit the content you would need to append or modify its `innerHTML`, like

```
rowx.cells[0].innerHTML="";
rowx.cells[0].appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create another image, you can simply change the `src` property of the current one:

```
rowx.cells[0].querySelector('img').src = uri;
```

---

If the image is the only (or 1st) element inside the cell, you can use `firstElementChild`, even better:

```
rowx.cells[0].firstElementChild.src = uri;
```

---

References: [querySelector](http://devdocs.io/dom/element/queryselector) and [firstElementChild](http://devdocs.io/dom/parentnode/firstelementchild)
.